# why am i not able to find height of my binary search tree?

Tags: search, tree, binary

This is the code I was trying to solve the problem mentioned in the question:

```
int getHeight(struct node* root) { // Write your code here
    int ldepth=0;
    int rdepth=0;
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    else{
        ldepth=getHeight(root->left);
        rdepth=getHeight(root->right);
        if(ldepth>rdepth)
            return ldepth+1;
        else (rdepth>ldepth)
            return rdepth+1;
        return 0;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to make sure your code is correctly formatted before you actually post your question. You should also tag the question with whatever programming language you are using

Answer (score 0):

If `ldepth==rdepth`, you return 0, regardless of their size:

```
int getHeight(struct node* root) { // Write your code here
    int ldepth;
    int rdepth;
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    else{
        ldepth = 1 + getHeight(root->left);
        rdepth = 1 + getHeight(root->right);
        return (ldepth > rdepth) ? ldepth : rdepth;
    }    
}
```